# Graphic Location Not Work Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

i'm using crystal report version 13

Graphic Location path work fine if the location is my local directory,
but it will show blank if i give path from another computer but i can open the image if i run the path manually.

i access the path using IP address -> share folder(eg: \\192.168.0.10\sharefolder\image.Jpeg), where permission is Full Control

i show the data (including image) to my form before print it using crystal reports. and the image is show correctly

is crystal report not support path from another computer?

Comment: I think your issue has to do with domain name resolution.  Given your two scenarios, referencing a local path is trivial. accessing a network location has some limitations. you have to consider who you are authorized as, what Permission Levels that user has for that network location.  Thirdly, and most likely to be the culprit is ... how you alias the location.  --- that path might be J:\reports\ on your laptop, but it has a more explicit name like: \\servername\logs\reports\ -- given: we do not know where the code will run, be SPECIFIC.

Comment: Are you debugging / monitoring the output of the operations? you should have more information than this.

Comment: i copy and run the output using windows run and it show fine

Comment: I think you want to test this: `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)` -- if that returns you data, then you move to step 2.  your report is either 1. inaccessible OR 2. in an unexpected format.

Comment: who ever down-voted this question isn't really reading the subject matter. :-)

Comment: this needs a double backslash (\192.168.0.10\sharefolder\image.Jpeg)

Comment: i show the data (including image) to my form before print it using crystal reports. and the image is show correctly

Comment: I would also recommend mapping your network path as a local alias on the report server.  it is a simpler short circuit to an otherwise trickier config. "z:\report20200220.pdf" vs. "\\domain\office\operations\stats\user-stats\report20200220.pdf"

Comment: I think then you are not clear on the Crystal Reports limitations on rendering images. I have ONLY had success with BMP (unfortunately) with Crystal 13. what format is your image?  See this guideline for image format support: https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1964141

Comment: I believe that Crystal Reports grabs the bytes from the file and then renders internally.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to map the network directory, where the file resides, as a MAPPED network drive.

the Crystal Report API operates better if the `path` is `R:\{CustomerNo}\{ProjectAlias}`